# On stream definition

Tags: java, stream, java-stream

In the [API reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) is written:

> A stream is a sequence of elements supporting sequential and parallel
>   aggregate operations

then,

> In this example, widgets is a Collection. We create a stream
>   of Widget objects via Collection.stream(), filter it to produce a
>   stream containing only the red widgets, and then transform it into a
>   stream of int values representing the weight of each red widget. Then
>   this stream is summed to produce a total weight.

again from the Java tutorial

> A stream is a sequence of elements. Unlike a collection, it is not a
>   data structure that stores elements

so, does or doesn't a stream contain elements?

Comment: No, a stream is a producer pattern. A collection has the elements all there and ready to go. A steam may calculate them on the fly. As collection must have finite length. A stream is often infinite.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, why is used the term "a stream containing..."?

Comment: I suppose because in this context the stream is of a collection.

Answer (score 1):

Streams define a logical organization of the data.  A stream may or may not "contain" elements in the sense of data stored in memory (physical organization).  They may instead be [lazily computed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate-java.util.function.Supplier-), allowing infinite size.

Collections also define logical organizations of the data. Collections might also be lazily computed: you could write a `List<T>` implementation that wraps a `Function<Integer, T>` that computes the result of `List.get(int)`.  Such a list would prohibit mutation.  (In functional languages using singly-linked lists as a the primitive data structure, arrays are sometimes represented as functions -- this `List`-from-function pattern could be seen as the inverse operation.)  Similarly a `Function<K, V>` could be viewed as an immutable `Map<K, V>`.  Infinite `List`s are a bit clumsier as `int` has finite range and thus `get(int)` can only access a limited range of the list, but they are possible.

Thus the logical organization of the data (list, map, stream) is mostly orthogonal to the physical layout (stored in an array or tree, or lazily computed from a function).  That's the point of both the collection and stream abstractions.